# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'parameters'

Tags: pytorch, resnet

I am using a modified Resnet18, with my own pooling function at the end of the Resnet.

Here is my code:

```
resnet = resnet18().cuda() #a modified resnet

class Model():
    def __init__(self, model, pool):
        self.model = model
        self.pool= pool #my own pool class which has trainable layers

    def forward(self, sample):
        output = self.model(sample)
        output = self.pool(output)
        output = F.normalize(output, p=2, dim=1)
        return output
```

Now, obviously I need to train not only the resnet part, but also the pool part.

But, when I check:

```
model = Model(model=resnet, pool= pool)
print(list(model.parameters()))
```

It gives:

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'parameters'
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need you `Model` to inherit `torch.nn.Module`:

```
class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model, pool):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        ...
```

Comment: Oh yes! right! Can you tell me how to print the parameters separately for the resnet and pool?

Comment: `pool` and `resnet` are themselves modules, so you can simply `print(model.pool.parameters())` (ditto for `resnet`)